# Can't select textarea resize handle on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, textarea

I've made a textarea in HTML and it works on most platforms. A specific exception is Android though. I've used `focus()` in the onclick handler for the textarea to make sure I can edit it. The resize handle isn't there in IE, but that's another question entirely.

I can't resize it with the handle in the corner.

I haven't returned false or anything in the click handler, so what's going on?

Comment: textareas resize handles are special features for some browsers not all of them!

Comment: I can see it here though, and it looks like I can resize it.